# problem formatting height <DD> for IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I'm trying to format DL list:

http://design.vitalbmx.com/new_html/index.html
(6 items starting with "Troy Merkle on Giant")

Looks good in Firefox, Chrome, IE7-8. 
In IE6 DD height is always larger (107px, while it must be 78px). I tried adding smaller height in  style, removing all margins / padding etc and nothing seems to help. Attached is a screen shot of what I see in Microsoft SuperPreview.
[alt text http://design.vitalbmx.com/new_html/dl-formatting.png](http://design.vitalbmx.com/new_html/dl-formatting.png)
Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving your anchor tag around the IMG a width and height, making it ipso-facto a block element. This is just a hunch, but try removing the anchor tag, put the mouse event handlers directly on the IMG, and setting the IMG to show a hand cursor with the style "cursor: hand"

Hope that helps.

Comment: Robusto you're a genius.
I didn't pay attention to <a> height in 'thumb' class.

I added this for IE6 only CSS file:
dl.list_compact dd div.thumb { margin-bottom:-28px !important; }

Fixed the problem.
Thanks!